# How do I align C++ comments to be compliant with Google styling?

Tags: filetype-c++, alignment, plugin-tabular

Any way to get Vim to format my comments to comply with Google cpplint?

[image]

Top section is not compliant, to comply 5 changes are required.

1. keep this comment at the same level
2. Add a space after `//`
3. add minimum of two spaces between code and comment
4. align comments
5. add space after `//`

(Note I am also asking this question here, it may be possible to do with Tabular https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular/issues/44)

EDIT: As per recommendation below, this works:

Plugin => https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format

.nvimrc or .vimrc Configuration:

```
let g:clang_format#code_style='google'

let g:clang_format#style_options = {
            \ "AccessModifierOffset" : -3,
            \ "Standard" : "C++03"}
```

Comment: clang-format has a googlestyle setting. I believe there is a plugin that you can use to run it from vim.

Comment: @FDinoff, awesome it works, if you answer, I will select it as solution...

Comment: I don't understand (1)--they both have four spaces before the first `/`, right?

Comment: @KyleStrand: I believe (1) has to do with *not* indenting that line to match the other two comments (i.e. OP is specifying an edge case that should not change).

Comment: @Kevin Ah, I thought it was saying it should be at the same indent-level as something on the previous or next line, but that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) is a command line tool that formats c++ code. One of the default formatters is google.

```
clang-format -style=google
```

There are plugins that would allow you to run clang-format in vim. One such plugin is https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format (I have not used it, it was the first I found)